# Issue with transform origin animation in Safari 12.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

Simple animation that changes the transform origin of a div based on horizontal mouse position.

It is not displaying the animation in Safari 12.1. Instead the div is stuck displaying the transform origin it had on page load (resizing the browser seems to update it).

The script is spitting out the correct values onto the element and no errors are showing up so need some help getting it animating.

It is working in latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari 11, just the latest Safari that is broken.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos){
    var xCord = getCurrentPos.clientX;
    var xPercent = xCord/window.innerWidth * 100 + "%";
    document.getElementById("p-beam").style.transformOrigin = xPercent + "100%"; 
});
```

```css
.beams {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #434343;
}

.p-beam {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -360px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 360px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), to(#eef));
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #eef);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(360px) rotateX(-104deg) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(360px) rotateX(-104deg) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="beams">
  <div id="p-beam" class="p-beam"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug.

I could get it working by changing the innerHTML/innerText of the bean, I think that way it forces layout/paint.

I'm concerned that the area you're paint is maybe too big, even if this is a bug, this could be too expensive and you're hitting the limits of the renderer. But this is just speculation.

I know it is not the same, but maybe you could accomplish something visually similar with just transform: rotate() or maybe transform: matrix()

```js
const beam = document.getElementById("p-beam");
let i=0;

setInterval(()=>{
  i=(i+1)%100;
  const x = `${i%100}% ${100}%`
  beam.style.transformOrigin = x;
  beam.innerHTML = i;
  //console.log(x)
}, 16);
```

```css
.p-beam {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -360px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 360px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: yellow;
  
  transform: perspective(360px) rotateX(-104deg) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="beams">
  <div id="p-beam" class="p-beam"></div>
</div>
```